# Remover todos los dígitos del comienzo de una cadena

Tags: oracle, regex, oracle-11g

Tengo la siguiente cadena '19827 PROTOMBINA TIEMPO PT' y quiero obtener la siguiente 'PROTOMBINA TIEMPO PT' utilizando alguna función que proporcione Oracle. Intenté la siguiente instrucción pero no funcionó.

```
select regexp_replace('19827 PROTOMBINA TIEMPO PT', '^[\d-]*\s*', '') from dual;
```

¿Estaré utilizando la expresión regular equivocada?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle soporta el uso de `\d`, pero no dentro de una clase de caracteres (no entre corchetes).

Al reemplazarlo por `0-9` se soluciona.

```
select regexp_replace('19827 PROTOMBINA TIEMPO PT', '^[-0-9]*\s*', '') from dual
```

- Demo: http://rextester.com/GZL21991

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias. Al final me decidí por '^([-0-9]|\s)*' para poder limpiar cadenas como esta '19827---56- 87 PROTOMBINA TIEMPO PT'

Comment: En ese caso, si sólo te interesa eliminar los espacios, yo usaría `^[-0-9 ]+` (el espacio dentro de la clase de caracteres). Es más prolijo y un poco más eficiente.